# Chat between players in Game Center turn based match

Tags: ios, game-center

I am trying to create a turn based game using Game Center. I wanted to know if it is possible to allow the players in the match to chat between each other (either voice or text).

I have looked into it a little and seems that it is possible via the normal game but not a turn based one.

If it is not possible what are the solution or ways to allow this type chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have text chat the following way: 
Without ending the turn, update the `matchData` object on the `GKTurnBasedMatch`. The updated NSData will be provided to all players that open your app and are participants in the game. So, your `matchData` object would have to carry both the game state and the chat state. Unfortunately, I do not see how one could trigger user notifications or badge the app for new chats without having to end the player's turn each time.